# How can I use ffmpeg to add music to a video being built from individual images with -filter_complex?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using `-filter_complex` to build a video out of several images, and fade them together. This is working fine. Now I'd like to add an audio track to the video, the command fails. How can I add audio to this video file I'm generating?

Here is what I'm doing that isn't working:

```
ffmpeg \
-i sunlight.mp3 \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 4.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 5.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

Here is the ffmpeg output from this:

```
    ffmpeg version 3.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
        built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
        configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --disable-lzma --enable-vda
        libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
        libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
        libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
        libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
        libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
        libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
        libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
        libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
        libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mp3, from 'sunlight.mp3':
        Metadata:
            encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
        Duration: 00:02:05.68, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
            Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
            Metadata:
                encoder         : Lavc57.48
    Input #1, image2, from '1.jpg':
        Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 42613 kb/s
            Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x900 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Input #2, image2, from '2.jpg':
        Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 44551 kb/s
            Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x900 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Input #3, image2, from '3.jpg':
        Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40433 kb/s
            Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x900 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Input #4, image2, from '4.jpg':
        Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 57157 kb/s
            Stream #4:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x900 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Input #5, image2, from '5.jpg':
        Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 51745 kb/s
            Stream #5:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x900 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; [2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; [3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; [4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v]; [0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v] matches no streams.
```

When I run the command without the `-i sunlight.mp3` it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two methods to try:

## Manually define output streams with `-map`

I usually recommend manually mapping your streams instead of relying on the default stream selection behavior so you don't get unexpected results, but this requires that you:

1. Label your filter outputs like you did with the `[v]`
2. Use `-map`

Example:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 4.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 5.jpg \
-i sunlight.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 5:a -shortest out.mp4
```

The [stream specifier](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) values you use in your [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) and in your [`-map` options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) depend on the order of your inputs.

## Use the default stream selection behavior

Since your final output contains only one video stream and one audio stream you can omit `-map` and the output label (`[v]`) and just use the [default stream selection behavior](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection). This may be the easier method to use if you're making a script.

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 4.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 5.jpg \
-i sunlight.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p" -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: It works and I don't know why so I'm off to read the links you posted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your script have two basic error:

1. in first filterchain (see first line of `filter_complex`) you specify `0:v` as an input stream. but as ffmpeg output says: `Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description ... matches no streams.` there is no video stream in file `0`. note that you send a `mp3` file as your first input. put it as last input file and ...
2. Add a `-map 5:a` before output file name.You specified video stream `[v]` as your only output stream. When using `-map` option, you must define all output streams with that.